# Error requesting https://sc1020.cm/sitecore/admin/PopulateManagedSchema.aspx?indexes=all

Tags: installation, sitecore-install-framework

I am facing an issue while attempting to install `Sitecore 10.2 XM` using the `Install-SitecoreConfiguration` command in PowerShell. During the installation process, I encounter the following error:

> Install-SitecoreConfiguration: Error requesting
> https://sc1020.cm/sitecore/admin/PopulateManagedSchema.aspx?indexes=all:
> The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error.

Also, When trying to install Sitecore 10.2 XM via graphical UI, I encounter another following error:

> [Error]: Cannot export non-exportable private key.

These errors consistently appear, preventing me from completing the installation successfully (both using Powershell and graphical UI ). I have followed the installation instructions meticulously and verified that all prerequisites are met.

I have made multiple installation attempts, but the error persists. I have also checked the Sitecore logs but haven't found any additional details to help troubleshoot the issue.

Has anyone else encountered a similar error during the Sitecore installation? What might be causing this error, and what steps can I take to resolve it? Are there any specific configurations or settings I should examine?

I would greatly appreciate any insights or suggestions on how to address this error. Thank you in advance for your assistance[image]

Comment: When you installed the certificate did you mark the private key as exportable?

Comment: @DeanOBrien I have not installed any third party certificates. Are you talking about installing any certificates? Please help

Comment: @SubhrajitMazumder Did you verify that you have installed `ASP component (ASP, ASP.net 3.5 and ASP.net 4.7)` in `Turn Window Features on or off` ?

Comment: Did you check the logs for errors? Also, is the PowerShell console running in Administrative mode? Running PS in non-admin mode denies permissions for calling external services.